# Save worksheets as individual workbooks as xls

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to save multiple worksheets in a workbook and save each worksheet as individual workbooks but starting from a specific tab and stop at the last tab it finds.  Below is the code I'm using but it keeps debugging after it copies one tab over.  Please note I'm also trying to copy over specific columns and hard code values (i'm copying over pivot tables).  Appreciate any help.

```
total_sheets = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count

For i = 6 To total_sheets

strshtname = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name

If srtshtname <> "Instructions, Macro Buttons, Pivot Data, Monthly Sales Data, invoice pvttbl template" Then

Sheets(strshtname).Select
Sheets(strshtname).Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\jreda\Desktop\PDFs Dump\" & strshtname & ".xlsx", _
     FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
     
     End If

Next

MsgBox "Excel Files Created & Saved"

End Sub
```

Comment: Check this article: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/628-excel-split-workbook.html

Comment: You can't call `SaveAs` on a `Range`. `FileFormat:=xlsText` doesn't make any sense either. Create a new workbook using `Workbooks.Add`, use `Range.Copy` to copy over just those columns, and then save the new workbook.